# Проблема с выгрузкой на GitHub

Tags: git, github

произошел такой конфуз, у меня было 2 акк в GitHub, про первый я успешно забыл и есть еще второй(основной), мой Git привязан к 1 аккаунту и выдает ошибку
[image: Ошибка с Гит]

Можете порекомендовать ршение проблемы, меня надо отвязаться с 1 аккаунта и привязать основной, но не через токены в GtiHub,как можно удалить файл с конфигом в винде,чтоб потом еще раз привязать акк?
Заранее всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете создать новый репозиторий на актуальном гитхаб аккаунте, далее склонировать его на компьютер через `git clone`, затем в склонированную папку перенести все файлы вашего проекта из старой папки, кроме .git, так как в git хранятся конфигурации от вашего прежнего аккаунта